# python dict not getting updated code block in for loop getting triggred again and again

Tags: python

below block of code is inside a for loop and I am trying to update dictionary outside for loop if this particular condition Mets but dict is not getting updated and this block is triggered again and again when a print(context.memory_df[sec_name + "_buy_trade_entry"]) it showing True tried lot maybe there's is some syntax error couldn't figure out

```
elif (context.current_time.time() >= datetime.time(context.memory_df["time_stop"][0],context.memory_df["time_stop"][1])) and (context.memory_df[sec_name + "_buy_trade_entry"] == True):
        print("16")
        context.memory_df[sec_name + "_buy_trade_entry"] == "time_exit"

        trade = [context.current_time,sec_name,context.memory_df[sec_name + "_atm_strike"],"BUY",
                            ce_price,pe_price,"exit",ce_wing_price,pe_wing_price,
                            context.memory_df[sec_name + "_what_to_buy"]]

        print(context.memory_df[sec_name + "_buy_trade_entry"]) # getting True instead of "time_exit"
        lv.save(context.memory_df_path,context.memory_df)
        lv.record_trade(trade,context.trade_rec_path)
        lv.record_trade(trade,context.every_day_trade_rec_path)
        order_placer(context,data,"long_exit_" + context.memory_df[sec_name + "_what_to_buy"],sec_name)
        winsound.Beep(2500, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

In third line from the top - you have double equality sign- just make it single one:

```py
context.memory_df[sec_name + "_buy_trade_entry"] = "time_exit"
```